# Проблема с роутингом реакт

Tags: reactjs

У меня есть роутинг, когда перехожу по оно добавляет к домену нужный путь, но не перенаправляет на страницу. Тоесть на какой был странице, такой и остался, но добавился путь с Link

```html
import './Login.css'
import logo from './images-general/logo.svg'
import imgRel from './images-general/indexImg.png'
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from 'swiper/react'
import "swiper/css"
import "swiper/css/pagination"
import { Pagination, Autoplay } from "swiper"


import { Link, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom'
import HomePage from './pages/HomePage'
import RegisterPage from './pages/RegisterPage'

function Login() {
  return (
    <div className="Login">
          <Routes>
              <Route path="/home" component={HomePage}/>
              <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage}/>
          </Routes>
        <div className="login-wrapper">
            <div className="login-left">
                <div className="login-container">
                  <div className="login-left-header">
                    <Link to="/login" className="login-logo">
                      <img src={logo} alt="logo"/>
                    </Link>
                  </div>
                  <div className="login-form">
                    <span className="login-form-title">Login</span>
                    <p>Sign in with your data that you entered during your registration.</p>
                    <div className="login-email">
                        <span>Email</span>
                        <input type="email" placeholder="name@example.com"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="login-password">
                        <span>Password</span>
                        <input type="password" placeholder="min. 8 characters"/>
                    </div>
                    <div className="login-check">
                        <input id="check" type="checkbox" />
                        <label for="check" >Keep me logged in</label>
                    </div>
                    <button className="login-confirm">Login</button>
                    <div className="login-rel-pass">
                        <button className="login-forgot">Forgot password</button>
                        <span>Don’t have an account?
                            <Link to="/register" className="login-signUp">Sign Up</Link>
                        </span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom"

const history = useHistory();

<Link
  className="login-signUp"
  onClick={(event) => {
    event.stopPropagation();
    history.push("/register");
  }}
>
  Sign Up
</Link>
```